# How did pirates back in the day not get killed themselves when they attacked ships?

Tags: 19th-century, 18th-century, 17th-century, ocean, pirates

Maybe I'm completely misinformed about how things were done "back in the day" (I imagine 1600s-1800s, when all ships were completely made out of wood with sails), but once the pirates had hoisted their Jolly Roger flag with the skull and bones, signalling that they were going to attack the victim ship, would it not be very common for the victim ship's crew to get ready with all their guns and cannons; prepare for "battle mode" to fight back against the pirates?

Since they did the flag thing, to give the victim the chance to surrender, I assume that they must have oftentimes done so. But I thought that people back then had many reasons to be much more defensive. For one thing, basic honor. But also probably laws against being a coward and harsh penalties resulting from a lost ship and/or valuable cargo.

It seems like a scary thought to me to return to your king (or whatever) and try to explain that pirates stole all that stuff you had spent months bringing back from them, and that you had not just taken it yourself. Thus, it seems very likely that hardened seamen in those days would indeed fight back rather than just surrender.

It's not like nowadays when nobody seems to care one bit about their work and just assume that "it will all be handled by insurance".

With that in mind, I cannot imagine that pirating would be very "jolly" for the pirates themselves. Would not every target be a basically 50/50 probability of getting killed? Or were pirate ships *much* more populated with blood-thirsty pirates and packed with heavy cannons than I have understood?

Perhaps I'm completely mistaken about the "average cargo ship" in those days? I imagine them being full of well-dressed soldiers like in 1950s movies such as *Crimson Pirate*, but maybe they were just a minimal crew of unarmed seamen with no battle experience or will to fight anyone? But even if that's the case, you'd think they would learn eventually to bring protection if pirates were that common?

Comment: A few points to consider here: (1) Hollywood movies are not a good place to start your research, (2) protection costs money and therefore is likely to greatly reduce the profits from the cargo carried, (3) pirate ships were more heavily armed and often faster than merchant ships. I believe pirate ships would often avoid heavily armed war ships.

Comment: Following comment for Lars Bosteen, a better place to start research than games and hollywood might be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Age_of_Piracy, noting that there were several short windows where piracy 'worked' and for much of history it was indeed a common for piracy to not work out. Recommend updating the question to focus a narrower time and place since the reasons changed.

Comment: This question desperately needs some focus. At the moment it covers three centuries and all of the oceans of the world. While Hollywood usually concentrates on the Carribean, piracy happened in places around the world - the pirates, their methods and motivations varied correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

The Somali pirates operate very much the same as pirates in the past. They use fast small ships and light weapons. Their most important weapon is fear. God help you if you resist, or try to resist!

**1- Commercial vessels were not well armed**

A gun is a very heavy object that lessens profit. Each gun weighs at least half a ton. Add to that ammunition and gun crew. Make it a ton altogether. A commercial ship is not a man of war. If it is equipped with 20 guns, it can carry 20 ton less cargo. Ships would carry as few guns as possible.

**2- Pirate ships were small and fast**

Pirates would operate small, fast ships, like [sloops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloop) or [schooners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schooner). They could be maintained anywhere. That's important, because they couldn't simply sail into a port and have it serviced there. A fast ship could outmanoeuvre any commercial ship. That's far more important than being large and impressive. Once a ship spotted a pirate, it had very little chance to escape. Unless it was close to port, or a warship was nearby.

**3- Pirates were ruthless**

What you never see in pirate movies is what pirates would do to anyone even attempting to resist. You'd be tortured in the most horrible way possible to death. Not just 'walking the plank', but in the most horrible way imaginable. Think: gauging out eyeballs, and having the victims eat them. That sort of thing.

That was simply good economics: anyone surrendering immediately had a *chance* on survival. Anyone remotely resisting, that might even be a dirty look, would be tortured to death. The result was that most merchantmen immediately surrendered without a fight.

That's not something Hollywood likes to show. Pirates were not "gentlemen of the sea". They were the absolute scum of the earth. Most people would barf if they knew what pirates would do to their victims.

- https://www.ranker.com/list/ways-pirates-killed/nathan-gibson
- https://www.pirateshowcancun.com/blog/jolly-pirate-speak/top-7-pirate-punishments-no-7-will-make-you-squirm/
- https://www.worldhistory.org/article/1847/pirate-punishments-in-the-golden-age-of-piracy/
- https://archive.archaeology.org/online/reviews/pirates/poll.html
- https://www.thevintagenews.com/2021/10/18/these-depraved-pirate-punishments-would-make-captain-jack-sparrow-shiver-his-timbers/?firefox=1
- https://listverse.com/2016/03/03/10-of-historys-most-terrifying-and-brutal-pirates/
- http://cindyvallar.com/torture.html

**4- There was no pirate flag**

Some pirates flew a [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jolly_Roger), but it wasn't standard practise. Some did, most did not. They flew any flag that would bring them closer to their victim.

> It's not like nowadays when nobody seems to care one bit about their work and just assume that "it will all be handled by insurance".

That's not correct. Ships were insured, most of them. Before the Golden age of Piracy, [the Dutch VOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_East_India_Company) was formed in 1602, precisely for that reason. A single ship was too costly, and the risks were too high for one investor. Piracy was just one of the many risks. Most nations followed, sooner or later, by setting up stock exchanges, insurance and companies with stocks. [Lloyds of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_of_London) was formed in 1686. Many if not most commercial long distance ships were insured.

Those ships were far more likely to surrender immediately. "The insurance will pay anyway." Ships that weren't insured and owned by the captain, or the owner present on the ship, would loose everything. They were more likely to resist.

> With that in mind, I cannot imagine that pirating would be very "jolly" for the pirates themselves.

No it wasn't. Conditions were pretty bad on board. Very cramped accommodations, bad food and a reasonable chance to get killed. Either by disease (most likely), or by combat, or later by hanging. Pirate ships were always small, but their captains tried to cram in as many crew as possible.

The upside was the pay and the more democratic working conditions. If a captain was successful, the pay was good. If not, no pay at all. Pirates usually elected their captain. An unsuccessful captain was swiftly replaced. If he was (very) lucky, by vote.

> Perhaps I'm completely mistaken about the "average cargo ship" in those days? I imagine them being full of well-dressed soldiers

Absolutely not! An average merchant sailor wasn't uniformed. Some captains paid for that, most did not. There were **no** soldiers on board. Even the gun crews were civilians. Almost always *(civilian)* sailors with some extra training. Perhaps a retired navy man would be there, but normally merchant ships sailed without military crew.

Comment: This answer should absolutely be backed by sources, e.g. for: pirate torture / "scum of the earth", "most merchantmen immediately surrendered". Also, while not the same thing at all, it might be worth mentioning privateers in addition to pirates.